# How to download file from a site without requiring any authentication, using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, network-programming, http-headers, httpcookie, setcookie

How to download file from a site without requiring any authentication, if the user is already signed in to the site? Are we supposed to pass cookies. How to do that? I am using firefox browser.Exact scenario is like this.
there is a site which require authentication. I want that after the user has logged into the site through browser, i want that my code should take that cookie from
cookie string provided by flashgot addon and send a get request to portal with that cookie so that authentication is not required. 
I tried this:
I am passing cookies through a string,

```
  cookie=rPopHome=1; FF_JoinPromo=true; __utma=140252452.845088738.1348089486.1348089486.1348089486.1; __utmb=140252452.6.10.1348089486; __utmc=140252452; __utmz=140252452.1348089486.1.1.utmcsr=adf.ly|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/7hYuB; ff_membership=SlyL0JODTZMIdfYHy/7imBJHqyHhO9ZHNE4bwnFPzoGYgPVEEneUMsfqaFDsqR+w9EotIx9i7PPL7ZIp1CiUSOtx0Y4mE1GmxayYmnJVD/z5aCTS2qT7fTItiqOprW8rlsEYw2Br7OoETaF3L1RGRQai1zlFQw6QO9qBEPKXC7rOx5LuEEKYlrZFKvuD/m7uDc6SWDJyaW67sRfo/bpb/Q==; ff_referrer_hash=o7e2qf0;

request.setUrl(url);
request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute, true);
cookieJar->setCookiesFromUrl(QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(cookie),url.host());
manager.setCookieJar(cookieJar);
reply=manager.get(request);
```

But i get the following error, the downloaded file contains this message:

```
<h1>HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized</h1>
     <p>You have attempted to download via a Premium download link, but we could not verify your Premium account details.</p>
     <p></h1>
```

I changed the user agent also,it still failed:

```
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would embed a *[QWebView](http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qwebview.html)* into the UI, then once the user is logged in via this browser you can access the *QNetworkAccessManager* that the page has configured to send the requests.

```
QNetworkAccessManager* getNetMan(const QWebView* view)
{ return view->page()->networkAccessManager(); }
```

This should have the cookie jar configured correctly, you may need to set the HTTP *Referrer* header as well for this sort of system to work to spoof the request fully.

If this doesn't work, use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to compare the requests from the browser and your application, and tweak your program until you have the requests matching.

Comment: I can't actually embed a QWebView. I am working on a downloader. Flashgot addon provides the cookie info related to url from which i download the file. The download is successful if i pass username and password when

    authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)

signal is emitted. But it fails with cookies. I wish to authorise using cookies passed on by flashgot addon

Comment: Have you compared the requests using Wireshark?

Comment: I have actually never used wireshark before. I am behind a proxy server in college hostel, and there is always a flood of packets being exchanged.

Comment: wireshark can filter packets. It's not difficult to isolate the ones you need.